# How to Require Custom Fields on Post From Another Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

Thanks for your time.

Getting into black magic between plugins here and I don't have too much knowledge on the right WordPressy way to go about this, so:

Let's say I have an arbitrary plugin that adds 3 custom fields to every Post, but it doesn't require them or offer a setting to do so, and I want them required without hacking that plugin.  What is the correct WordPress approach to enforce that they are filled with something valid on Publish?

Comment: You are looking for [Action/Filter Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks)

Comment: I didn't know those could be used to hook fields in other plugins?  I thought a hook had to be installed in WordPress for me to be able to leverage it?